# Skype Alpha Install Problem ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, skype

Recently i had this problem to install Skype DEB or via repo:

https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading-web/?type=weblinux-deb

See the log:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  imported-Humanity/192 of theme Lubuntu has no size field
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libpango1.0-0:amd64.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 228056 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../libpango1.0-0_1.40.1-1_amd64.deb ...
A descompactar libpango1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.1-1) ...
Configurando libpango1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.1-1) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado skypeforlinux.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 228063 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../skypeforlinux_1.6.0.3_amd64.deb ...
A descompactar skypeforlinux (1.6.0.3) ...
Configurando skypeforlinux (1.6.0.3) ...
Warning: The postinst maintainerscript of the package skypeforlinux
Warning: seems to use apt-key (provided by apt) without depending on gnupg or gnupg2.
Warning: This will BREAK in the future and should be fixed by the package maintainer(s).
Note: Check first if apt-key functionality is needed at all - it probably isn't!
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package skypeforlinux)
OK
/etc/aptsources.list.d is not a folder
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote skypeforlinux (--install):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
A processar 'triggers' para hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
```

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/skypeforlinux.postinst` and replace

```
FULLSOURCEDIR=$ROOTFOLDER$ETCFOLDER$SOURCEDIR
```

with

```
FULLSOURCEDIR=$ROOTFOLDER$ETCFOLDER/$SOURCEDIR
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

To install skype you need to enable the Canonical partner first:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
skype
```

Or you can install it following the steps described [here](https://repo.skype.com/):

> `# make sure you have 'apt-transport-https' installed

```
dpkg -s apt-transport-https > /dev/null || bash -c "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https -y" 
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux -y
```

`
[**Edit**](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34656/more-information-about-skype-for-linux-alpha)

> Skype for Linux Alpha depends on `gnome-keyring` and `libgnome-keyring0` packages for storing credentials. Both of these packages are installed as a dependency for the Skype for Linux Alpha package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0
```

Comment: Same problem after all steps: '
Warning: The postinst maintainerscript of the package skypeforlinux
Warning: seems to use apt-key (provided by apt) without depending on gnupg or gnupg2.
Warning: This will BREAK in the future and should be fixed by the package maintainer(s).
Note: Check first if apt-key functionality is needed at all - it probably isn't!' ... :-(

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install gnupg2`

Comment: Good tips but the suggestion from @JasonPeters solved the problem.